# Are there any remote flash triggers capable of adjusting power output of a Nikon SB-28 in manual mode?

Tags: off-camera-flash, studio-lighting, remote

I've just started experimenting with off camera flashes using my film SLR cameras and a Nikon SB-28 speedlight that is capable of manual power control.

It seems I would benefit from being able to adjust the power without going up to the flash every time. Initially I was using the simplest radio triggers.

Are there any radio triggers that can specifically control above flash, or what specifications should I look for in this regard? I saw some triggers are able to do this with an LCD screen, I'm just not sure what is compatible with what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The [Cactus V6 triggers list the SB-28 as compatible](https://www.cactus-image.com/v6.html) (the SB-24, too). That is, there's a profile for that flash with the V6 that allows for M power control.  The SB-28 is *not* compatible with the newer V6 II transceivers.

I suspect that Cactus has deciphered how the TTL signalling for the SB-28 can be manipulated to "fake" M power settings, despite the fact that it only does film-era TTL.

See also: https://www.cactus-image.com/community/discussion/1525/v6-firmware-v2-1-001-nikon-sb-28-as-main-flash as it looks like which firmware version is loaded can affect the functionality.

Comment: Thank! Sound great. I haven't really heard about this trigger before but the V6 seems to be just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to remotely control the power output of older film era Thyristor flash units.

If it were a newer iTTL flash unit designed for Digital SLR cameras, there would be multiple options for remote control.